# Cannot convert Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameterCollection to Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter

Tags: vb.net, oraclecommand

I am using an sql command to store a command text and some parameters:

```
myOracleCommand = New OracleCommand

With myOracleCommand

    .CommandType = CommandType.Text
    .CommandText = "MY QUERY"
    .Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter("Test1", OracleDbType.Varchar2, "05", ParameterDirection.Input))
    .Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter("Test2", OracleDbType.Varchar2,   DBNull.Value, ParameterDirection.Input))
    .Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter("Test3", OracleDbType.Int32, DBNull.Value, ParameterDirection.Input))
    .CommandTimeout = 60

End With  

' But after running this :

ExecuteReader("T3B", myOracleCommand.CommandText.ToString, Text, myOracleCommand.Parameters)
```

Then I am getting this message error :

> Cannot convert a value of type ' Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameterCollection ' to ' Table 1 dimension ( s) Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter '

What should I do to fix the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe, I know the answer for your issue. In this line

```
ExecuteReader("T3B", myOracleCommand.CommandText.ToString, Text, myOracleCommand.Parameters)
```

you use `myOracleCommand.Parameters`, which is of type `OracleParameterCollection`,  wile `ExecuteReader` expects array of `OracleParameter`.

What you need to do is convert this collection to an array and pass that array. And for that `OracleParameterCollection` has method `CopyTo`. So, it is trivial

```
Dim a(myOracleCommand.Parameters.Count - 1) As OracleParameter
myOracleCommand.Parameters.CopyTo(a, 0)
ExecuteReader("T3B", myOracleCommand.CommandText, Text, a)
```

Note: `ToString` is not needed in `CommandText.ToString()` because command text is already a string